# Arraylist to array of integers, can't get it to work (java)!

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm creating a method to take the averages of all the even numbers of an array.

How can I convert the arraylist object (evens) to an array, so I could sum them up?

```
    public static double percentEven(int[]a)
    {
    ArrayList evens = new ArrayList();
    int evenSum = 0;


    for (int counter = 0;counter < a.length;counter++)
    {
        if ((a[counter]%2) == 0 )    
        evens.add(a[counter]);
    }    

    int[] evenReturned = new int[evens.size()];
    evens.toArray(evenReturned);

    int evensCount = 0;
    for (evensCount = 0;evensCount < evens.size();evensCount++)
    {
        evenSum += evenReturned[evensCount];   
    }    


    return evenSum/evensCount;

  }
```

Comment: Why do you want to convert it to an array, there is no need to do this? You can sum them up perfectly fine from the ArrayList as is.

Comment: Why don't you do the averaging directly on the array? Just maintain the sum and count of the even elements. Add the end return `sum / count`. BTW, that last part is what you are forgetting now too.

Comment: ON a side, note, how do you properly convert an arraylist to array?

Answer (score 7):

Why are you collecting them? Just sum them!

```
int evensCount = 0;
int evenSum = 0;
for (int counter = 0; counter < a.length; counter++) {
    if (a[counter] % 2 == 0) {
        evensCount++;
        evenSum += a[counter];
    }
}

return evenSum/evensCount;
```

Answer (score 2):

Though you don't need to do it here but to convert ArrayList to Arrays do this:

```
List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
T [] yourArray = list.toArray(new T[list.size()]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sum them up, then just use a specialized for loop to go through each element in the evens ArrayList, for example

```
for (int e : evens)
{
   evenSum += e;
}

return evenSum/evensCount;
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to do this

```
if ((a[counter]%2) == 0 ) { 
    evenCount++ ;
    evens.add(a[counter]); // required only if you want an array of even numbers 
    evenSum += a[counter] ;
}
...
...
return evenSum / evenCount ;
```